# HTML markup not displaying from within php if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress theme with a brief summary, with css styling, at the top of a post. This is wrapped in an if statement to only display if there is a summary.

Using the code below, the summary text displays, but the surrounding HTML markup is not included in the page source.

```
<?php if (get_smry_text($post)) { ?>
<div class="summaryWrap">
    <div class="sumText">
        <p><?php get_smry_text($post); ?></p>
     </div>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that `get_smry_text()` doesn't return any values.
 Instead it echoes the content directly.
If you are using [this function](https://github.com/tonyedwardspz/Portfolio/blob/master/functions.php) you can do something like this:

```
<?php if ($smry = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'smry_text', true)) { ?>
<div class="summaryWrap">
    <div class="sumText">
        <p><? echo $smry; ?></p>
     </div>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Perfect...and kudos on the homework! If I understand it now, the code within the if statement gets skipped completely, and instead the if condition itself is echoing the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<?php
   $smry_text = get_smry_text($post);
   if ($smry_text) {
       $text = '<div class="summaryWrap">
               <div class="sumText">
                 <p> ' . $smry_text .  '</p>
               </div>
           </div>';
        echo $text;
   }
?>
```

Comment: And this does what? It won't even compile now, unfortunately.

Comment: Using this the summary text does not display at all :(

Comment: Then get_smry_text must not be returning anything